# return jsonresult behaves unexpextedly with jquery post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Okay please help, I've been frustrated with this issue.

I need to either set an error value or perform a redirect when a user hits the submit button. (its a standard login form). I need to do it with ajax.

I think its almost working, however when the user clicks submit the page just displays:
{"redirect":"/Home/Index"}

or
{"error":"The user name or password provided is incorrect."}

its not redirecting/displaying the error how I'm intending it to.

some background - the form is a login form, and its placed inside a modal popup dialog.(jqueryui)

Heres my jquery:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
            $.post({
                url: "Account/LogOn",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.redirect) {
                        // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                        window.location.href = data.redirect;
                    }
                    else {
                        // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                        $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

and heres my Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Json(new { redirect = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { redirect = "/Home/Index" });
                }
            }

        }
        return Json(new { error = "The user name or password provided is incorrect." });
    }
```

heres is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
{

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: why can't you just do the redirect from the controller `HttpPost`? (e.g `RedirectToAction` - which also satisfies the PRG pattern). Why do you need to return JSON and then do it client-side?

Comment: Perhaps i can do the redirect, but I also need to cover the case of displaying the error through ajax. I cant redirect to another page in this instance because the login form is inside a modal dialog

Comment: Are you sure that your click-function is running? Regarding to your description it sounds like the form is submitted the usual way. Use http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ at the bottom of the function.

Comment: Sorry, of course at the top of the function ^^

Comment: i'm also curious as to the 'value' of the json return value. how does it play out in the grander scheme?? is it purely to handle the error portion?? if so, i would be tempted to do this with standard partialviews (plus the redirecttoaction), rather than complicating the plumbing. that said, i could well be missing something subtle.

Comment: @jim yes its to handle displaying the error in order to display it within the modal dialog.

Comment: raklos - got the picture now. will add a quick answer below

Comment: @Dr.Molle I think you may be right, but not sure why? I tried what you said though but that doesnt work- the form does nothing when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, the whole $.post()-call is wrong.

Use this:

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {e.preventDefault();
            $.post( "Account/LogOn",
                    $(this.form).serialize(),
                    function (data) 
                    {
                      if (data.redirect) 
                      {
                        // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                        window.location.href = data.redirect;
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                        // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                        $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                      }
                    },
                    'json'
            );
            return false;
        });
```

You've used the notation of the arguments like expected in $.ajax() , but in [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it's different.